# Why is REINFORCE loss differentiable?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Here is some sample REINFORCE code found in the [PyTorch distributions docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html):

```
probs = policy_network(state)
m = Categorical(probs)
action = m.sample()
next_state, reward = env.step(action)
loss = -m.log_prob(action) * reward
loss.backward()
```

I don't understand why this loss is differentiable. In particular, how does `m.log_prob(action)` maintain the computational path of the network output `probs`? How are `m.log_prob(action)` and `probs` are 'connected'?

Edit: I looked at the [implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/distributions/categorical.html#Categorical.log_prob) of `log_prob`, and it doesn't even seem to reference `self.probs` anywhere; only `self.logits`.

Comment: You might have missed that logits are a function of probs `def logits(self): return probs_to_logits(self.probs)`

Comment: @lejlot You're right! I only saw `logits` in `__init__` and didn't realize it was set automatically if the user provided `probs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lejlot noted in the comments, if a `Categorical` object is constructed with `probs` rather than `logits`, then `logits` is later *defined in terms of* `probs`. Hence, when `logits` is used in `log_prob`, the gradients from `probs` are propagated. I missed this connection between `logits` and `probs` because it doesn't occur in `__init__`, but instead, `logits` is a `lazy_property`.